# Any way to trigger a Shortcut based on notifications from a given app?

Tags: notifications, shortcut, automation

The app does not have any awareness of Shortcuts (it doesn't come with any of its own Shortcuts etc). But it does reliably send a particular notification, with particular text, which I would like to use to trigger something. I’m looking to do this on any version of macOS, iOS and/or iPadOS.

Is there any way that I could trigger a Shortcut/Automation based on a notification from a particular app?

Comment: Are you using shortcuts app on macOS, iOS or iPadOS?

Comment: @bmike All three.

Answer (score 3):

No, it's not currently possible. The Shortcuts app doesn't have access to notifications from other apps.

Comment: OK, thanks. Do you know there's *any* way (not with Shortcuts) for any non-Apple application/service/script/whatever to read current notifications, on iOS, iPadOS or macOS? If there's some other way, in theory I can hook it up via a webhook via Pushcuts or something. But maybe Apple keeps it locked down for security/privacy reasons.